# Finding the limit points of a constant sequence in $X$ with a given topology.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

My question is about finding the limit points of a sequence in a topological space.

Say I have $X = \{0,1\}$ with a topology $T = \lbrace \emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\} \rbrace$.

If I have a constant sequence $0,0,0 . . .$

then I know that such a sequence would converge to $0$ if our domain was the real numbers. (Similarly for any constant sequence in the real numbers).

Of course, for topologies it's a bit different.

A point $x$ in $X$ is a limit point of some subset $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ different from $x$ itself.

My thought here is that a sequence of $0$s can only have 0 as a possible limit point. Hence the above condition is not true for a sequence $0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0. . . $ where it would be true for a sequence $1,1,1,1,1,1,1. . .$.

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The point $1$ has one and only one neighborhood, which is $\{0,1\}$. Since $0$ belongs to it, $1$ is a limit point of the sequence $0,0,0,\ldots$.

Note that $0$ is *not* a limit point of the sequence $1,1,1,\ldots$, since $\{0\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$ to which $1$ does not belong.